# Can't connect to mysql db using root@localhost in a mamp environment

Tags: mysql, localhost, mamp

I'm working on a MAC in a MAMP environment.
so when i try to connect to the database i get this error

```
$this->db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
```

I can log in with PhpMyAdmin as the root user.

> mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

my root user is set like this

```
user: root
machine: localhost
password: no
global rights: ALL PRIVILEGES
grant: yes
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem?

Comment: I think you have set a password somewhere. Even when you have your options on password: no. I don't know Mamp because I'm a windows user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP Manual [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) says about the password field:

> If not provided or NULL, the MySQL server will attempt to authenticate
>   the user against those user records which have no password only. This
>   allows one username to be used with different permissions (depending
>   on if a password as provided or not).

So, either do `mysqli_connect($host, $user);` or `mysqli_connect($host, $user, null);`

Comment: i've tried this and some things have changed, but i'm not sure if the connection is a success now.
I'll keep you informed

Answer (score 0):

you have to call mysqli_connect without a password parameter, else php tries to authenticate the user using the empty string as password. try

```
mysqli_connect($host, $user);
```

only, withouth the `''`.